# Deactivate featured post click through in header of wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, posts, wordpress-featured-image

I've purchased a premium WP theme that has a header which rotates between five featured posts/photos.  My hope is to keep the visual appeal of this without clicking through to the post itself. Any ideas on how to deactivate the click through? Here is the PHP code for the featured posts. Happy supply more code / to share the dev site itself if needed.

http://pastebin.com/vJwbJBap

The theme is located at: http://www.mojo-themes.com/demo/siucco-wordpress-theme/

Many thanks,

Alex

Comment: Can you supply a link to the theme or a screen shot please.

Comment: Thinking the header code will be needed as well. http://pastebin.com/endQqfje

Comment: @RobertPitt Surely, here is the theme: http://www.mojo-themes.com/demo/siucco-wordpress-theme/ Thank you!

Comment: If you purchased this theme then you should also have support from the provider. They have probably already been asked this question and have a ready-made answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it via jquery.. inside off your "demo.js" add this inside window load function(){}

```
$("#slider a.nivo-imageLink").attr('href', '').click(function(){return false});
```